# What is the role of the asterisk before the parameter?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
np.meshgrid(*[np.arange(x) for x in a.shape])
```

What is the role of the asterisk before the parameter?

[image: code]

why does it works? what dose it mean adding an asterisk before list comprehension as a parameter?

Comment: Please update your question with an actual snippet of code, not an external image.

Comment: @Soviut - I don't think it matters much. It's a common duplicate anyway.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This is the first time I have asked questions in stackoverfolw, sorry for asking a duplicate question

Comment: Don't worry about it. Just, maybe Google a bit more next time. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I will ,thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, an `*` unrolls a list.

That way you can use a list as a set of arguments.

```
some_args = ['first', False, 3]

do_something(*some_args)
```

In your case, the following is unrolling a list comprehension.

```
*[np.arange(x) for x in a.shape]
```

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question, which was about function calls, not function definitions.

Comment: I think I get your point! Thank you

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You're right, I've updated my answer.